# Value of k that will make $p(x)$ a probability function

Tags: probability

Find: value of k that will make $p(x)$ a probability function.

1. $p(x) = k(\frac{1}{9})^x$ , for $x = 1,2,3...$
2. $p(x) = kx^2$, for $x = 1,2,3...,n$

In my attempt to solve, I set my integral from $1 \to \infty =  1$. The function inside being $k(\frac{1}{9})^x$. Integrating, I get $k = 9\ln 9$. However, when I attempt to plug this back in to verify I actually get $1$, I do not.

Similar to $1$., setting the integral = to 1 with function inside being $kx^2$, I get $k = \frac{3}{x^3}$

I realize my thought process in solving these problems must be incorrect. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: These are discrete distributions with probability mass functions. Integrals are useful (indeed, necessary) when you have continuous probability densities, but for discrete mass functions you use summations (as you have seen in the answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p:S\to\mathbb{R}$ is a probability mass function on $S$ if $p$ is nonnegative and $\sum\limits_{s\in S}p(s)=1$. In the first case, we have $S=\mathbb{N}^+$ and $p$ is obviously nonnegative so:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(n)=1\\k\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{9^n}=1$$Do you know how to evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{9^n}$?

---

For our second case, we have $S=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ and $p(x)=kx^2$ so $$\sum_{x=1}^n p(x)=1\\k\sum_{x=1}^n x^2=1$$Do you know how to write write $\sum\limits_{x=1}^n x^2$ in closed form?

Comment: I am not sure how to evaluate the series above. It has been some time.. I am looking this up now.

Comment: @samp1920 hint: $$S=r+r^2+r^3+\dots\\rS=r^2+r^3+\dots\\S-rS=\,?$$

Comment: ok! yes thank you!

Answer (score 3):

These are discrete variables. You must use a series in the first exercise and a finite sum in the second one, not integrals. Note the tags, "for $x=\ldots$".

Answer (score 1):

You have in both cases a discrete random variable. Thus you have to use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) for the infinite geometric series.

Hint: In case of 1. you have the equation

$k\cdot \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{9} \right)^x=k\cdot \frac{1}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{9}}=1 $

Then solve for k.

Comment: the link to the formula was helpful. Things are coming back to me now.

Comment: We all become older and our memory sometimes needs a stimulus.

Answer (score 0):

to the case 1) note that $x$ is an integer:

$$1 =\sum_{x=1}^\infty  k \frac{1}{9}^x = k\frac{1}{8}$$

this gives $k = 8$

for the case 2

$$1 =\sum_{x=1}^n  k x^2  = k \bigg(n (n+1) \frac{(2n+1)}{6}\bigg)$$

this gives $$k = \frac{1}{\bigg(n (n+1) \frac{(2n+1)}{6}\bigg)}$$

Comment: Thanks @conrado. Might you be able to explain how you arrived at your answer for case 1 and I will try to apply the same logic to case 2? I am rusty with series.

Comment: The factor 9 is not necessary. $k*\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{9} \right) ^x=\frac{k}{8}$